# jQuery Running total and output label not working...

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please review the fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/WuMpz/)**.

There are two things I can't seem to accomplish here.

*I would like to see a running total of the input amounts and it's not working. It only shows the running total after I start to input the third value. I'd like to see it start after I enter the first value.

```
var updateTotal = function () {
  var input1 = parseInt($('#earnedAid1').val());
  var input2 = parseInt($('#earnedAid2').val());
  var input3 = parseInt($('#earnedAid3').val());        
  $('#total').text(input1 + input2 + input3);
};
```

*Secondly, I am trying to display an output label and it's not showing up either.

```
   output_total.text(total+" in Retained Aid");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with the output label solved. Also the code is cleaned a bit. There was logic that was duplicated from the UpdateTotal function into the remainder of the external/anonymous function. The new code registers the key up events. Then defines the function to compute the total.

http://jsfiddle.net/WuMpz/3/

```
$('#total').text(input1 + input2 + input3+" in Retained Aid");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is stemming that when the inputs have no value, they result in `NaN` when you try to perform math operations. Simply put, if there is no number, assume that `0` can be used:

```
var input1 = parseInt($('#earnedAid1').val() || 0);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WuMpz/1/

And your label isn't showing up because on each `keyup` stroke, you're replacing that label with the total of your inputs.

Comment: That worked great. Any thoughts on the output label?

Comment: Removing the `.keyup(function()` doesn't work. Any ideas there?

Comment: Yes, add the text you want in the label to the keyup function call: http://jsfiddle.net/WuMpz/4/ -- @webfrogs